# How to remove dependencies in this OpenMP summation exemple

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, dependencies, openmp

I'm starting with OpenMP now, and need to achieve parallelism in this task with OpenMP:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
 index += i*alpha + 4;
 sum += array[index];
}
```

I intend to use reduction operator to get the correct value of sum variable , but in order to do that I need to solve the dependency of the index variable first.
How can I do that?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop cannot be straightforwardly parallelized because of the **sequential dependency**. However, it can be first **split in two parts**:

```cpp
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
 index += i*alpha + 4;
 tmp[i] = index;
}
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
 sum += array[tmp[i]];
}
```

Once split, the first loop exhibits a **scan pattern** and can be parallelized although the parallel version may not be faster than the sequential one. The second loop is a simple **reduction** that can be quite easily parallelized.

Performing a scan patterns with OpenMP is usually a bit tricky. Hopefully, because *`alpha` seems to be a loop constant*, all the value of **`index` can easily predicted** thanks to basic math properties:

```
index_i = index_init + 0*alpha+4 + 1*alpha+4 + 2*alpha+4 + ... + i*alpha+4
        = index_init + (0+1+2+...+i)*alpha + 4*(i+1)
        = index_init + (i*(i+1)/2)*alpha + 4*(i+1)
        = index_init + (i+1)*(i*alpha + 8)/2
```

Thus we can write the final resulting code:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
 sum += array[index + (i*(i+1)/2)*alpha + 4*(i+1)];
}
```

Moreover, if `alpha` is an integer and `index` starts from zero, the array indexing can be made slightly faster:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
 sum += array[(i+1)*(i*alpha+8)/2];
}
```